# How to use virtualservice to expose dashboards like grafana prometheus and kiali?

Tags: kubernetes, grafana, istio, istio-kiali

I have my dashboards exposed to `<dashboard>.foobar.com` with no problem, now I am trying to expose dashboards mentioned above to `www.foobar.com/dashboard/<kiali>`
I have tested with a simple .net backend container with this VS set up:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: whatever
spec:
  hosts:
  - www.foobar.com
  gateways:
  - some-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /bla
    rewrite:
      uri: " "
    route:
    - destination:
        port:
          number: 1234
        host: dummy-service
```

Then I have:
`foobar.com/bla/api/hello` -> `dummyservice/api/hello`
`foobar.com/bla/api/deeper/hello` -> `dummyservice/api/deeper/hello`
which is good.
However, if I apply the same to those dashboards, nothing works!
Here is my setting for the dashboards:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: dashboards
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  hosts:
  - www.foobar.com
  gateways:
  - default/somegateway
  http:
  - name: grafana
    match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /dashboards/grafana
    rewrite:
      uri: /
    route:
    - destination:
        port:
          number: 80
        host: grafana.grafana.svc.cluster.local
  - name: prometheus
    match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /dashboards/prometheus
    rewrite:
      uri: "/"
    route:
    - destination:
        port:
          number: 9089
        host: prometheus-server.prometheus.svc.cluster.local
  - name: kubernetes-dashboard
    match:
    - uri:
        prefix: "/dashboards/kubernetes"
    rewrite:
      uri: " "
    route:
    - destination:
        port:
          number: 8443
        host: kubernetes-dashboard.kubernetes-dashboard.svc.cluster.local
  - name: kubernetes-dashboard
    match:
    - uri:
        prefix: "/dashboards/kiali/"
    rewrite:
      uri: /
    route:
    - destination:
        port:
          number: 20001
        host: kiali.istio-system.svc.cluster.local
```

As someone mentioned there is a known issue with `/` and   so you can see I have `rewrite` for both of them. But still nothing works.
I got 404 for most of them, and grafana redirects me to `www.foobar.com/login`

Anyone have done this before? I am thinking of maybe these dashboards are frontend included, so its not that simple as my .net backend container?

Comment: Hi. Can you try adding 2 uri matches for each : eg. "/dashboards/kiali/" and "/dashboards/kiali" (in that order), then rewrite to "/". Also, can you post the logs from the kiali/grafana istio-proxy when you try to access these services ?

Comment: Also please check this : https://grafana.com/tutorials/run-grafana-behind-a-proxy/ Pretty sure there will be something similar for kiali

Comment: `grafana redirects me to www.foobar.com/login` That's how the app is configured, I've explained it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67161545/11977760). I assume it's the same for kiali and prometheus. So your istio configuration is correct, but if want to have `/dashboards/kiali` and others on same host then you would have to configure your applications for that.

Comment: Thanks @LudovicC , I realized that the apps like these guys need extra configurations on them. I have made Prometheus and Grafana working now, I will answer my question after I make all of them working.

Comment: And also thanks @Jakub, I am working on change the configurations for the apps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For anyone has the same question, please take a look here:

I have this resolved:

So first, the VirtualSerive are correct, but remember to add quotes to write section:

```
    rewrite:
      uri: "/"
```

And prefix sections need to be closed with a `/`

```
  - name: kubernetes-dashboard
    match:
    - uri:
        prefix: "/kubernetes/"
```

Here comes the trick, prometheus and grafana are designed to be worked at root url. However, its configurable in the `deployment.yaml`
For example, I want my grafana and prometheus works at `www.foobar.com/grafana/` and `www.foobar.com/prometheus` respectively.
In grafana `deployment.yaml`, we need to specify:

```
          env:
            - name: GF_SERVER_ROOT_URL
              value: 'http://localhost:3000/grafana/'
            - name: GF_SERVER_DOMAIN
              value: localhost
            - name: GF_SERVER_SERVE_FROM_SUB_PATH
              value: 'true'
```

And in prometheus, it has the similar:

```
- name: prometheus-server
    image: 'quay.io/prometheus/prometheus:v2.24.0'
    args:
      - '--web.enable-lifecycle'
      - '--web.external-url=https://localhost:9090/prometheus/'
      - '--web.route-prefix=/'
```

For kiali, the trick is in virtual service, you have to rewrite it to `/kiali/`:

```
  - name: kiali-dashboard
    match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /kiali/
    rewrite:
      uri: "/kiali/"
```